# How to show remote participant video on Twilio programmable video?

Tags: javascript, twilio-video

I have web page with the following JavaScript code.

My code is listening to **participant connected** event on a certain room. Whenever a new participant is connected, I need to show his remote video.

Here is my code:

```
    var LastTrack;

    function trackSubscribed(HtmlParent, track) {   
        LastTrack = track;  

        console.log("the track width is : " + track.dimensions.width);
        console.log("the track Height is : " + track.dimensions.height);
        HtmlParent.appendChild(track.attach()); 
      }
      
    function participantConnected(HtmlParent, participant) {    
        participant.tracks.forEach(publication => {
          if (publication.isSubscribed) {
            trackSubscribed(HtmlParent, publication.track);
          }
          else { console.log('Track not subscribed'); }
          
        });
        
        participant.on('trackSubscribed',   track => trackSubscribed(HtmlParent, track));
        
      }
```

This code never works the first time. The remote video is not added the HTML DOM and in the logs I have:

```
the track width is : null
the track height is : null
```

However if I call the manually (few seconds later) the function **trackSubscribed(HtmlParent, LastTrack)** then it works. The video is shown as expected and the dimensions are correct:

```
the track width is : 640
the track height is : 480
```

It's like when I'm trying to add the track to the HTML DOM the first time, the track is not "ready".

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: It's normal for the track to not have a width/height at the instant you first receive it.  In fact, you can expect that width/height to change over time.  However, it's strange that the video isn't getting appended.  Can you confirm that `HtmlParent` is what you expect it to be within `trackSubscribed`?